# listbox selected item changed event fired two times

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Am using the below code for selected index changed event. Event fired two times i cant able to fix this error . Please help me to fix this error..

This is my code:

```
   if (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i <= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
       {
           if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected == true)
           {
               lblempid.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[i].Text.Substring(0, 8));
               lblempname.Text = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.Items[i].Text.Substring(9));
               DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter();
               DataSet5.sp_GetallpayperiodDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
               if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   fromdate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstartdate"]);
                   todate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldtodate"]);
                   status = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstatus"]);
                   if (status == "OPEN")
                   {
                       lblfromdate.Text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", fromdate);
                       lbltodate.Text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", todate);
                   }
               }

           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: This is the code u want to execute when event is fired,this is not the cause of event, so u have to provide the code if u are firing custom event or may be u are repeating ur code 2 times

Comment: No error Displayed. But Event fired two times..

Comment: You may be wiring up the event twice?  Do you have the method/code where the event is being wired up?

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code where you are calling for the event?

Comment: also could you show us how you setup your onSelectedIndexChanged from your .aspx file?

Comment: Are your labels linked to some TextChanged event and in this event you change the ListBox1 index?

Comment: @romfernando: show us your Page_Load().

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your Page_Load handler. If you're setting the selection of the list box in there, you need to bracket it thus:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ListBox1.SelectedItem = "your old selection";
}
```

Otherwise you'll see the handler fire twice, as you describe.

Also: this is not an answer to your question, but you might want to get rid of that loop:

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

string theItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

lblempid.Text = theItem.Substring(0, 8);
lblempname.Text = theItem.Substring(9);
DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter TA 
    = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_GetallpayperiodTableAdapter();
DataSet5.sp_GetallpayperiodDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    fromdate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstartdate"]);
    todate = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldtodate"]);
    status = Convert.ToString(DS.Rows[DS.Rows.Count - 1]["fldstatus"]);
    if (status == "OPEN")
    {
        lblfromdate.Text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", fromdate);
        lbltodate.Text = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", todate);
    }
}
```